# stoping async tasks running in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to run through (using foreach) an array of objects and then for each I'd like to call a function that uses request to get a file and then unzips it with zlib, but one at a time, given the nature of node this is currently done asynchronously.

I'd like it to be done something like this...
- foreach - first object
- call function for first object
- when function has completed
- go to the next object in the array

I have tried using the [SYNC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync) module to try and solve this but with no luck.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

```
// the function i am trying to run for each in sync    
var downloadUnzipFile = function(mID) {
      try {
        // Read File
        console.log("Started download/unzip of merchant: " + mID + " @ " + new Date().format('H:i:s').toString());
        request(linkConst(mID))
          // Un-Gzip
          .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
          // Write File
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName(mID)))
          .on('error', function(err) {
            console.error(err);
          })
          .on('finish', function() {
            console.log("CSV created: " + fileName(mID));
            console.log("Completed merchant: " + mID + " @ " + new Date().format('H:i:s').toString());
            //console.log("Parsing CSV...");
            //csvReader(fileName);
          });

      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }

    module.exports = function(sMerchants) {
      var oMerchants = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sMerchants));

      sync(function() {
        oMerchants.forEach(function eachMerchant(merchant) {
          downloadUnzipFile(merchant.merchant_aw_id);
        })
      })

    };
```

Comment: `forEach` is not the way to go. Like you have already said. You need to use a `promise` or a `callback` so that when the first one completes it calls the next one.

Comment: Does node.js have generators yet? I use iojs, so the above is a breeze using function* and promises - having said that, I've wrote, just 24 hours ago, a "Promise queue" which will handle this exact type of scenario in ES5, if you're interested

Comment: highland by caolan can do this quite nicely, without needing generator support.  http://highlandjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your function needs to take a callback so it can communicate when it has finished:

```
var downloadUnzipFile = function(mID, next) {
  try {
    // Read File
    console.log("Started download/unzip of merchant: " + mID + " @ " + new Date().format('H:i:s').toString());
    request(linkConst(mID))
      // Un-Gzip
      .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
      // Write File
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName(mID)))
      .on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .on('finish', function() {
        console.log("CSV created: " + fileName(mID));
        console.log("Completed merchant: " + mID + " @ " + new Date().format('H:i:s').toString());
        //console.log("Parsing CSV...");
        //csvReader(fileName);
        next();
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    next();
  }
}
```

Then, we need to recursively call each one when the previous has finished:

```
module.exports = function(sMerchants, next) {
  var oMerchants = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sMerchants));
  var i = 0;

  var run = function() {
    if(i < oMerchants.length)
      downloadUnzipFile(i++, run);
    else
      next();
  };
};
```

Note that I also added a callback to the exported function, so it can communicate when it is finished.  If this is unnecessary, you can drop it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var promiseQueue = (function() {
    'use strict';
    var promiseQueue = function() {
        var queue = [Promise.resolve(true)];
        var add = function(cb) {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            args.shift();
            queue.unshift(new Promise(function(resolve) {
                queue[0].then(function() {
                    resolve(cb.apply(null, args));
                    queue.pop();
                });
            }));
        };
        return {
            add: add
        }
    }
    return promiseQueue;
}());
```

usage EXAMPLE:
This is the asynch function that will be called

```
var theFun = function (time, n) { // use whatever arguments you like that will be called with your function
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        //asynch function goes here INSTEAD of the setTimeout and it's contents, I repeat, INSTEAD of the setTimeout
        setTimeout(function() { // this is for demonstrating ONLY
            console.log('resolving', n, time); // this is for demonstrating ONLY
            resolve(time); // this is for demonstrating ONLY
        }, time); // this is for demonstrating ONLY
        // remember to resolve("someValueNotImportantAsItIsntUsedAnywhere") on completion of your asynch function
    });
}
```

This is how the items get added to the queue - I did it this way because of MY use case

```
var pq = promiseQueue();

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    var r = 1000 - i * 150;
    console.log('adding ', i, r);
    pq.add(theFun, r, i);
}
```

Hope you find this of some use

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you, uses [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Need to add `resolve` and `reject` callbacks to your `downloadUnzipFile`-

```js
var exports = (function () {
    'use strict';
    
    var pre = document.getElementById('out');
    
    function log(str) {
        pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str + '\n'));
    }
    
    function downloadUnzipFile(id, resolve, reject) {
        log('Start: ' + id);
        
        try {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve(id);
            }, 3000);
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    }

    function done(id) {
        log('Done: ' + id);
    }

    function error(e) {
        log(e.message);
    }

    function getPromise(mID) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            downloadUnzipFile(mID, resolve, reject);
        });
    }

    return function (sMerchants) {
        JSON.parse(sMerchants).reduce(function (next, mID) {
            if (!next) {
                next = getPromise(mID);
            } else {
                next = next.then(function (id) {
                    done(id);
                    return getPromise(mID);
                }, error);
            }

            return next;
        }, null).then(done, error);
    };
}());

exports(JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20150503/json2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.1.7/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise/master/dist/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

I added the browser shims to support older browsers that may be viewing this, you shouldn't need them on `node.js` but you may need to `require` a `Promise` shim if you are using an old `node.js`.